# Macro- Execute .exe after Post-Built Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, macros

I want to write Post-build event in visual studio 2012. and I dont know how to write Macros to execute post built events. My simple requirement is, i just want to run an .exe file which is placed in a folder after successful built operation. So please guide me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this code

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
shell.Run "C:\YourProgram.exe"
```

Note : Your can adjust your path

Comment: when i am using this macro,  My project is not building. i am getting error 174 03073 "Commannd " exited with code 9009.

Comment: beacause you have not trsuted path, i suggest to set in your path the shotcut,  $(SolutionDir) or $(TargetPath)